# checkbox checked - assign value to variable and send in a submit

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have this piece of code, and I'm trying to assign a value to variable `days` (if one of the combinations of checkbox checked are true), and send by submit to another asp.

The problem is that the variable doesn't take any value. Here's the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function validatedays(days) {
var dias=3
if(document.getElementById("chkmonday").checked && document.getElementById("chktuesday").checked) 
    { var days=1;}
if(document.getElementById("chkwednesday").checked && document.getElementById("chkthursday").checked)
    { var days=2;}
if(document.getElementById("chkfriday").checked) {
    var days=3 }
datos.submit()
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" id="data" name="data" action="blabla.asp">
<input type="text" name="txtsurname"  id="txtsurname" size="20" /><br />
<input type="text" name="txtcuota" id="txtcuota" size="20" /><br />
<br />
<input type="checkbox" value="chklunes" name="chkmonday" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="chkmartes" name="chktuesday" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="chkmiercoles" name="chkwednesday" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="chkjueves" name="chkthursday" /><br/>
<input type="checkbox" value="chkviernes" name="chkfriday" /><br/>
<br/>
<input type="submit" value="Calcular" onclick="javascript:validatedays(days)" />  
<input type="reset" value="Clean" /> 
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if you expect to see the value of `days` in $_POST you need to use a hidden field to send it, also can't you figure out the value of `days` server side based on the value  of your checkboxes? if you don't really care for "chklunes", "checkmartes", etc. then just put 1,2,3 as the value of the checkbox

Comment: it's not important the value of the variable, i'm going to put 1,2,3,4,5.  I only need to evaluate the condition, asign a value to the variable and evaluate later in a function. thks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `var` keyword declares a variable in the current scope. You need to declare days in the scope of your whole function. Then you need a way to pass your value in the form: this is usually done with a input type="hidden".

```
function validatedays() {
    var days;

    if(document.getElementById("chkmonday").checked && document.getElementById("chktuesday").checked) {
        days=1;
    } else if(document.getElementById("chkwednesday").checked && document.getElementById("chkthursday").checked) {
        days=2;
    } else if(document.getElementById("chkfriday").checked) {
        days=3;
    }

    // Assign days to the value of a (hidden) input in the form

    document.getElementById('data').submit();
}
```

Your button being a type="submit", I think you don't need the last line (unless you cancel the event).

Comment: Thank you... i didnt realize that declaration was not declared on all the function.  I'm very rookie on this subject. :(

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do `var <name of the variable>` you are redeclaring it when you don't have to. So remove the `var` keyword.

Also, you were missing some `;` and most importantly, you hadn't defined `datos` (which, I guess was supposed to be the form).

```
var datos = document.getElementById('data');

function validatedays(days) {
    if (document.getElementById('chkmonday').checked
            && document.getElementById('chktuesday').checked) {
        days = 1;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("chkwednesday").checked
            && document.getElementById("chkthursday").checked) {
        days = 2;
    }

    if (document.getElementById("chkfriday").checked) {
        days = 3;
    }

    datos.submit();
}
```

Comment: Using an undeclared variable makes it belong to the global scope (in HTML, that's the `window` object). `days` being local to a function, it's bad practice and could conflict with a variable used in some other included Javascript. Always declare your local variables with `var`.

Comment: @Pikrass In this case `days` is not actually _undefined_, it is the parameter of the function. OP wanted to modify it for some reason.